# Confused between Real AJAX & ASP.net AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Its been more than 1 year I am working with ASP.NET. I use update panels and they update the page asynchronously without causing a postback.

I thought this is all about Ajax. Until I heard that ASP.NET AJAX is not real AJAX. Is it ?

And also that Real Ajax is much faster and efficient that ASP.NET AJAX.

## What is this real ajax and where do I get started to learn it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think real ajax referred here is the Ajax library which can be used to perform variety of options. Asp.Net Ajax have only limited option like update panel. Ajax library can provide a good number of extenders and other new controls.